# Append function does not add anything to the panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arcpy

I have the following code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import pandas as pd

#setting workspace
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\4_projects\211104\Network.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True  #existing output will be overwritten
buchs = r"buchs"

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(buchs)
shapeName = arcpy.Describe(buchs).shapeFieldName

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapeName)
    extent = feat.extent
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"XMin": [extent.XMin],
                "YMin": [extent.YMin],
                "XMax": [extent.XMax],
                "YMax": [extent.YMax]})
    df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

My goal is to extract from every `row` the X and Y extent by creating a temporary df `df2` and then append this to `df1`. So `df1` is supposed to have row by row, all the extents of every entry. However, my `df1`always results in an empty df.

Any help is appreciated. If additional data is necessary, please let me know how to best share a shapefile here, thank you.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your file `Network.gdb` (wetransfer, dropbox, ...), please? Maybe you could use Geopandas.

Comment: Also, you can change your pattern to build `df1`. The best strategy is to collect data in a python data structure like dict or list and finally use `pd.concat` to build your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `DataFrame.append()` has to be assigned to a variable, otherwise it does append the other dataframe, but never assigns it and it's gone as soon as the appending finishes, so just add `df1 =`  in front of the append:

```
    df1 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

you can use

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

if all the columns are matched

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution related to my comment above:

```
data = []
for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapeName)
    extent = feat.extent
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"XMin": [extent.XMin],
                "YMin": [extent.YMin],
                "XMax": [extent.XMax],
                "YMax": [extent.YMax]})
    data.append(df2)

df1 = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```